# Qual a diferença entre viewDidLoad e awakeFromNib?

Tags: ios, swift

Qual a principal diferença entre **viewDidLoad** e **awakeFromNib** no desenvolvimento em Swift para iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` é um método de `NSObject` e é chamado assim que o objeto é criado a partir de um arquivo do Interface Builder (ex: .xib)

`viewDidLoad` é um método de `UIViewcontroller` chamado após a view do ViewController ser criada

Em outras palavras `awakeFromNib` é chamado em qualquer objeto definido no interface builder (subclasses de UITableViewCell, UIView, UIViewcontroller, etc). Já `viewDidLoad` é invocado somente em subclasses de `UIViewcontroller`, independentemente da forma que a view foi construída. Ou seja, mesmo se a view for criada programaticamente, usando `loadView`, o método é chamado.

Em resumo, `viewDidLoad` é normalmente usado para inicialização de ViewControllers e `awakeFromNib` é usado para outras classes criadas com o Interface Builder como TableViewCells